# Column-count is not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, column-count, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a text splitted in 4 columns and it works perfectly in Safari I don't know why I can see just 2 columns in Google Chrome.

Tested with Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
#people{
 -webkit-column-count:4;
 -moz-column-count:4;
 column-count:4;
 -webkit-column-gap:.5em;
 -moz-column-gap:.5em;
 column-gap:.5em;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 font-size:18px;
 line-height:21px;
}

.keeptogether{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div id=people>
<div class=keeptogether>
A<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>

<br>B<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>C<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
D<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>E<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>F<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>G<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>H<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>I<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>J<br>
<br>K<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
L<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>M<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>N<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>O<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>P<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<span class=yes><br></span>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
Q<br>
<br>R<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>S<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>T<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>U<br>
<br>V<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>W<br>
<br>X<br>
<br>Y<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>Z<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it is not working in the latest Chrome then it must be some sort of regression. In an older version of Chrome, I do see 4 columns.

Comment: A regression indeed. There's a workaround - using `break-inside: avoid-column` rule, like in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/spng58tb/1/) - but it seems to be not supported by Firefox.

Comment: @raina77ow I've tried that break-inside but it still doesn't work as it should

Comment: In addition, it seems that Chrome does not support columnar layout for the  `<fieldset>` element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to your `#people` id in your css:

```css
#people{
  display: flex;
 -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
 column-count: 4;
 -webkit-column-gap:.5em;
 -moz-column-gap:.5em;
 column-gap:.5em;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 font-size:18px;
 line-height:21px;
}

.keeptogether{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id=people>
  <div class="keeptogether">
  A<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>

  <br>B<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>C<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  </div>
  <div class="keeptogether">
  D<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>E<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>F<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>G<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>H<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>I<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>J<br>
  <br>K<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  </div>
  <div class="keeptogether">
  L<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>M<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>N<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>O<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>P<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <span class="yes"><br></span>
  </div>
  <div class="keeptogether">
  Q<br>
  <br>R<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>S<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>T<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>U<br>
  <br>V<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>W<br>
  <br>X<br>
  <br>Y<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  <br>Z<br>
  fhdjsklfhs<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Still the easiest solution (that actually works) over 5 years later!

Comment: Flex is similar, but the end result is not quite the same, depending on your data.  Flex will wrap divs below the longest div on the previous row, potentially leaving large gaps, whereas columns will leave no such gaps.

Comment: This is far from being a solution to the issue.  Please, do not answer if you do not have real solutions just to get the reward from less experienced users. You are adding a lot of noice and degrading the quality of this forum.

Answer (score 9):

Replace `display:inline-block` by `display:block`.

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn), for Chrome issue, you should add `-webkit-perspective:1;` on the container.

```css
#people{
 -webkit-column-count:4;
 -moz-column-count:4;
 column-count:4;
 -webkit-column-gap:.5em;
 -moz-column-gap:.5em;
 column-gap:.5em;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 font-size:18px;
 line-height:21px;
 -webkit-perspective:1;
}

.keeptogether{
  display:block;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div id=people>
<div class=keeptogether>
A<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>

<br>B<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>C<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
D<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>E<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>F<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>G<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>H<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>I<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>J<br>
<br>K<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
L<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>M<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>N<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>O<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>P<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<span class=yes><br></span>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
Q<br>
<br>R<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>S<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>T<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>U<br>
<br>V<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>W<br>
<br>X<br>
<br>Y<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>Z<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solution from caniuse refers to another issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `display: flex;` to `#people` ID, then it works fine in all the browsers and you don't need `display:inline-block;` for `.keeptogether` class.

You can check the code snippet:

```css
#people {
 -webkit-column-count:4;
 -moz-column-count:4;
 column-count:4;
 -webkit-column-gap:.5em;
 -moz-column-gap:.5em;
 column-gap:.5em;
 display: flex;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 font-size:18px;
 line-height:21px;
}

.keeptogether {
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div id=people>
<div class=keeptogether>
A<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>

<br>B<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>C<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
D<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>E<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>F<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>G<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>H<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>I<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>J<br>
<br>K<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
L<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>M<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>N<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>O<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>P<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<span class=yes><br></span>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
Q<br>
<br>R<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>S<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>T<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>U<br>
<br>V<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>W<br>
<br>X<br>
<br>Y<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>Z<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to give `display: inline-block` ? the concept of using `column` property is to divide your whole given content into equal width columns. So if you remove your inner-div, the all content gets properly aligned into given number of columns.

This also works, if you remove `inline-block` from your current code.

```css
#people {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: .5em;
  -moz-column-gap: .5em;
  column-gap: .5em;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
}


/* you don't need this property
.keeptogether {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
*/
```

```html
<div id="people">
  A<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>

  <br>B<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>C<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> D
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>E<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>F<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>G<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>H<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>I<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>J<br>
  <br>K<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> L
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>M<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>N<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>O<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>P<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <span class="yes"><br></span> Q
  <br>
  <br>R<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>S<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>T<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>U<br>
  <br>V<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>W<br>
  <br>X<br>
  <br>Y<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
  <br>Z<br> fhdjsklfhs
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar method for a WordPress theme. It looks pretty good in Firefox and displays two columns in place of four in Chromium/Chrome for full screen width.

When I increased the number of posts per page (bricks), the number of columns increased to fill up the space.

Chrome seems to render three or more bricks before graduating up to the next column.

Comment: Yes this problem is still present in 2020; that Chrome (only), refuses to use more than 2 columns unless it features more bricks (6+)

Answer (score 1):

After suffering this issue with Chrome 80.0 the solution was from a comment on the question:

```
.childbrick {
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

This fixed both the odd lack of columns in Chrome as well as the column splitting which occurred if not using `display:inline-block;` .

[**The comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985733/column-count-is-not-working-in-chrome#comment71149783_41985733) references a Firefox issue with this workaround but I have found no such issues with Firefox version 73.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with this issue i found out -webkit needs to come last (Otherwise I guess it tries to use the non webkit and fails)

```
        column-count: 2; 
        -moz-column-count: 2; 
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the `.keeptogether` rules and it will work fine. Additionally, I recommend you always add the `column-width` rule in order to make it more responsive, as that rule sets the minimum size for each column.

```css
#people{
 -webkit-column-count:4;
 -moz-column-count:4;
 column-count:4;
 column-width: 120px;
 -webkit-column-gap:.5em;
 -moz-column-gap:.5em;
 column-gap:.5em;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 font-size:18px;
 line-height:21px;
}

/*.keeptogether{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%
}*/
```

```html
<div id=people>
<div class=keeptogether>
A<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>

<br>B<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>C<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
D<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>E<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>F<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>G<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>H<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>I<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>J<br>
<br>K<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
L<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>M<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>N<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>O<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>P<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<span class=yes><br></span>
</div>
<div class=keeptogether>
Q<br>
<br>R<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>S<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>T<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>U<br>
<br>V<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>W<br>
<br>X<br>
<br>Y<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
<br>Z<br>
fhdjsklfhs<br>
</div>
</div>
```